# What does // refer to when you have nested Buck projects?

Tags: git, buck

I am using Buck to build my project, but I have a complicated folder structure due to the use of Git submodules. My project layout looks like this:

```
+ root
+-- .buckconfig // X
+-- BUCK // A
+-- main.cpp
+--+ library // Git Submodule!
   +-- .buckconfig // Y
   +-- BUCK // B
   +--+ anotherLibrary
      +-- .buckconfig
      +-- BUCK // C
```

In `BUCK` file C, I have a path like this: `//:library`. When not used as a submodule, `//` will be resolved to `library/`. This is the behaviour I want, even when `library` is a submodule.

In the above layout, will `//` be resolved to `.buckconfig` X or `.buckconfig` Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you run `buck` from.  If you run the [`buck root`](https://buckbuild.com/command/root.html) command, it'll tell you where `//` refers to.

It looks like you might want to take advantage of a feature of Buck that isn't documented (and still changing) called Cells.  The best documentation for that is likely [one of Buck's tests](https://github.com/facebook/buck/tree/master/test/com/facebook/buck/crosscell/testdata/intracell/visibility).