# How do cells work in Buck?

Tags: buck

I understand that there is an [undocumented feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41810968/1256041) in [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) called cells. There are [some tests](https://github.com/facebook/buck/tree/master/test/com/facebook/buck/crosscell/testdata) that demonstrate how they work, but is there any more written information about them?

How do cells work in Buck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this example repo](https://github.com/njlr/buck-cells-example).

---

**What Problem Does Cells Solve?**

Cells are a great fit for this situtation:

- You have a library in a repo that builds with Buck
- You want to use that library in your project
- You copy the library into your project but the library's `BUCK` files don't work, because the root (`//`) has changed to the root of your project
- You don't want to rewrite your library's `BUCK` files!

Cells allow us to create isolated sub-projects that have their own `.buckconfig` and their own Buck target heirarchy. Cells can use targets from other cells when those targets are exported.

**How Does it Work?**

The meat of the example is in `.buckconfig`:

```
[repositories]
  neither = vendor/neither
```

The repositories tag tells Buck where each cell lives in your project's folder structure. Each cell has an alias. Here we have `neither = vendor/neither`, which means the subfolder `vendor/neither` is a cell with the name `neither`.

We can refer to targets inside of a cell using this syntax: `cell-name//:target-in-cell`.

So to make our example target depend on [LoopPerfect/neither](https://github.com/LoopPerfect/neither):

```
deps = [
  'neither//:neither',
],
```

This is a really powerful feature, because it makes a library's `BUCK` files portable. All you need to do to expose a target inside of a cell is to make it public:

```
visibility = [
  'PUBLIC',
]
```